# wifi роутер. Не заходит в панель управления

Tags: wifi

Всем привет!

Да я знаю, вопрос может быть и не по теме форума, но все же это моя очередная отчаянная попытка получить доступ к панели управление wifi маршрутизатора.

Примерно три года назад купил я себе роутер, настроил его и работал он 2,5 года. Далее произошло что-то непонятное, когда я ввожу в адресной строке браузера локальный ip адрес роутера(в данном случае 192.168.1.1 - в этом ip я уверен, т.к. проверял на многих устройствах) страница не загружается и выдает ошибку, в chrome что-то такое 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(поверял также и в других браузерах). При этом роутер выполняет свои функции(раздает wifi и интернет LAN).

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Подскажите пожалуйста, я уже отчаялся.

P.S. Также пробовал сбросить роутер до заводских, после сброса он перезагружался и через некоторое время снова раздавал wifi, при этом настройка не нужна и доступа к панели тоже нет.

Comment: На моем TPLink, так бывает при долгой работе, но после перезагрузки (выключения/включения физически) доступ восстанавливается к управлению. P.S. Загляните в инструкцию, у него может ip устанавливается по умолчанию не 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Нет, по умолчанию у него как раз 192.168.1.1, также я еще лок сеть проверял, там точно 192.168.1.1

Comment: А модель роутера можно узнать?у меня где то был файл типа базы знаний по их ошибкам попробую поискать

Comment: У вас при долгой работе роутера тоже не заходит в панель управления?

Comment: TL-WR841N, TP-LINK фирма

Comment: Да, именно при долгой работе доступ отваливается. Есть даже более новая прошивка для моего роутера в которой обещают исправление, но лень делать обновление :)

Comment: переверни.обычно на таких написан стандартный логин пароль и ип прямо на этикетке!если не войдет значит ктото его сменил

Comment: Кстати, прошивка, об этом я и не думал, а как они вообще прошиваются, через какой разъем я имею ввиду?

Comment: Дело не в том что я пароль забыл, у меня это окно спроса логина и пароля даже не появляется, страница не загружается вообще

Comment: фича в том ип роутера можно поменять. если ты и до этого когда либо заходил ччерез 192.168.1.1 то это плохо. попробуй 192.168.0.1

Comment: а он вообще работает по своему прямому назначению?

Comment: Да, wifi раздает

Comment: вероятно прошивка

Comment: Да, это единственный выход, перепрошить, лан пошёл инфу в интернете искать

Comment: В том-то и проблема, что через web-интерфейс заливается.

Answer (score 1):

У самого похожая проблема. Вылечилось покупкой нового блока питания и сбросом настроек. Вот никогда не мог бы подумать, что так вылечить можно.

Можно попробовать отключить от сети физически (вынуть из розетки и разъем блока питания), подождать пару часиков, и не подключая ничего кроме питания и одного порта включить. Быть может, оживет на полчасика?

Еще нельзя забывать про собственную глупость: фильтрация мак-адресов тоже может давать похожий эффект. Ну и всякие антивирусы и фаерволы.